# How to enforce variable typing in Named Tuple in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, typing, namedtuple

I am following this [tutorial](http://alpopkes.com/posts/2018/08/coding-challenge-day-10-and-11/) on named tuple with specification of variable types. However, I modified the code (below), and even if I enter values of wrong types, there was no error message or programming break as a result. I understand you can write your own try/except to raise error exception, but is there a readily-available solution/syntax to enforce users entering the right type of variables.

```
from typing import NamedTuple

class Pet(NamedTuple):
    pet_name: str
    pet_type: str

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{self.pet_name}, {self.pet_type}"

cleons_pet = Pet('Cotton', 'owl')
print('cleons_pet: ', cleons_pet)

cleons_pet_v2 = Pet(222, 1)
print('cleons_pet_v2: ', cleons_pet_v2)

# Output
cleons_pet:  Cotton, owl
cleons_pet_v2:  222, 1
[Finished in 0.1s]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type hints in python will not be evaluated by python itself! See [PEP484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/)

> While these annotations are available at runtime through the usual **annotations** attribute, no type checking happens at runtime. Instead, the proposal assumes the existence of a separate off-line type checker which users can run over their source code voluntarily.

There are at least two projects which offer offline type checking ([mypy](http://mypy-lang.org/) and [pyre](https://pyre-check.org/)). You should definitely use them if you are using type hints in your project.

If you want to validate the input while running the application, you have to either convince the offline type checkers by validating the data by yourself or use a third-party library. I know of [attrs](https://www.attrs.org/en/stable/), where you can use [validators](https://www.attrs.org/en/stable/examples.html#validators) or [type annotations](https://www.attrs.org/en/stable/types.html) for online validation.